# IIS_WPG (and IIS_IUSRS) member of "Authenticated Users" group?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

I need a confirmation that IIS_WPG and the newer one IIS_IUSRS are also members of the "Authenticated Users" group. Can someone confirm this or am I wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The IIS_WPG user is a the IIS Worker Process Group, and is needed in order for IIS to run / access applciations within a folder

The IIS_IUSRS is a the Internet Guest Account, this is used to allow anonynous access to the folder / files. This is needed if you want the general public to be able to view anything in the folders e.g. a website.

They are not norally part of the "Authenticated Users" group and normally require you to grant access seperatly.

Comment: Oh IIS 6 only not sure about IIS 7

Comment: I think so maybe of IIS_IUSRS,but not of IIS_WPG.Try a research with a client certificate for which your IIS_WPG have to access its private key and you'll see! It is ok if you give +r to AUTHENTICATED_USERS and you don't have to give that right for IIS_WPG!

Comment: Can I ask, by "access applications" do you mean things like a webservice. Can I assume it does not mean javascript or vbscript .. or does it ?